# QtCreator (2.7.0) does not process properly LIBS.

Tags: qt4, qt-creator, qmake

I have defined the following environment variable:

`PLATFORM_SDK=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0`

Inside my project file I declared:

`LIBS += $$quote($(PLATFORM_SDK)/lib/SHFolder.lib)`

This results in:
`Linker return error: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Program.obj'`

The following declaration also produces the same error:

`LIBS += $$quote(-L$(PLATFORM_SDK)/lib) -lSHFolder`

However, if I specify the same path explicitly, as follows, it works:

`LIBS += $$quote(C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0/lib/SHFolder.lib)`

To me this looks like a `qmake` bug.

Unfortunately, an environment variable for the LIBS definition is a requirement.
Does anybody know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not reproduce your problem.

I created a new environment variable `PLATFORM_SDK` with the given value: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0`. Then I restarted Qt Creator and checked that PLATFORM_SDK can be found in the list of environment variables (see [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator/creator-build-settings.html#build-environment)). Then I created a simple .pro file and put the following lines there:

```
LIBS = $$quote($(PLATFORM_SDK)/lib/SHFolder.lib)
message($$LIBS)
LIBS = $$quote(-L$(PLATFORM_SDK)/lib) -lSHFolder
message($$LIBS)
LIBS = $$quote(C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0/lib/SHFolder.lib)
message($$LIBS)
```

After running QMake I got the following results (in `Compile Output`):

```
Project MESSAGE: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0/lib/SHFolder.lib
Project MESSAGE: -LC:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0/lib -lSHFolder
Project MESSAGE: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0/lib/SHFolder.lib
```

That is, your first and third declaration gave exactly the same results, there was no problem in using an environment variable.

EDIT:
After the conversation in the comments below I can try to explain what was the problem.

qmake is a tool that creates Makefiles based on the information in your .pro file. In .pro files variables can be used to store the contents of environment variables. These can be evaluated either at the time that qmake is run, or included in the generated Makefile for evaluation when the project is built. If you use the `$(...)` operator then the contents of the environment variable will be obtained when the generated Makefile is processed. However if you use the `$$(...)` operator then the contents of the environment variable will be obtained when qmake is run, that is, when your Makefile is generated.

In your case if you have the line `LIBS += $$quote($(PLATFORM_SDK)/lib/SHFolder.lib)` in your .pro file then your Makefile will contain this line: `LIBS = $(PLATFORM_SDK)/lib/SHFolder.lib`. But if you have this line `LIBS += $$quote($$(PLATFORM_SDK)/lib/SHFolder.lib)` in your .pro file then your Makefile will contain this line: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0/lib/SHFolder.lib"`.

As you can see the main difference is that in the former case the line generated into the Makefile is not enclosed in double quotes which will be a problem because your environment variable contains a path having spaces. I do not know why the double quotes are missing in the former case. They should be there because you used function `$$quote(...)`.

Comment: Hi,

Function 'message' work fine. In my project too.

Problem is that **linker** return error.

  Marek

Comment: @MarekGruszewski Strange. By using function `message` I tried to demonstrate that the value of variable `LIBS` will be the same when you set a path indirectly through an environment variable and when you set it explicitly. If the value of `LIBS` is the same in both cases then how can you get a linker error in the first case and how can it work in the second case? It should either work or not work in both cases, should not it?

Comment: I agree in 100%. I tested in same way as you. Unfortunately it work fine for message(), but not for linker. I think that problem is connected with space inside path and from unknown reasons $$quote() didn't help. Try link, you will see that linker say that cannot open 'C:\Program.obj'

Comment: @MarekGruszewski I have an idea. Try `$$(PLATFORM_SDK)` instead of `$(PLATFORM_SDK)`, that is use two `$`s instead of one. I'll give explanation if it works.

Comment: I defined inside project file

Comment: new variable PLSDK = $(PLATFORM_SDK)

Comment: and used $$PLSDK instead $(PLATFORM_SDK). Same effect

Comment: @MarekGruszewski Please try what I have suggested: `LIBS += $$quote($$(PLATFORM_SDK)/lib/SHFolder.lib)` and let's see what happens.

Comment: @MarekGruszewski I've edited my answer and put there my explanation. I hope it is clear.

Comment: Thank you again for help and clear explanation. Do you agree that it looks like bug in qmake?